# Blogs in slider

Tags: magento2, slider, blog

I'm using Mageplaza blog extension to create blogs, now I need to show those blogs in a slider, What I have to do? I'm new to Magento. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mageplaza blog extension User guide for Easy to understand

all the configurations in this extension

**[Mageplaza blog extension user guide](https://docs.mageplaza.com/blog-m2/)**